# Color changes automatically on zoom

Tags: highcharts

Problem: 
When i zoom in and out (with the buttons), the color of the zoomed area changes (becomes darker).

Is this a known issue/bug? How can i prevent this color change?
(tested in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Chrome and Opera.)

Here is my code:

```
$(function() {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },

            series : [{
                name : '1',
                data : data,
                color: '#FF0000',
                type : 'area',
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                },
                stacking: 'normal'
            },{
                name : '2',
                data : data,
                color: '#A6A6A6',
                type : 'area',
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                },
                stacking: 'normal'
            },{
                name : '3',
                data : data,
                color: '#D9D9D9',
                type : 'area',
                tooltip : {
                    valueDecimals : 2
                },
                stacking: 'normal'
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5fpCP/1/

Comment: For sure there is bug reported on github tracker, unfortunately I can't find it right now..

Comment: Are you sure it's already reported?

I looked at [https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues) and didn't find it.

Comment: Never mind, they fixed it in their latest version.